# Xamarin Forms PopModalAsync()

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Working with Xamarin Forms, on iOS, pusing a modal using

```
  await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new mypage());
```

When I call

```
  await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

from mypage it pops all the way back to root instead of where I just called push from.   There's no code anywhere else interacting with the modally pushed page

Comment: So...what's your question?

Comment: I need it to only pop back to where I called Push from, not all the way back to the root

Comment: await Navigation.PushAsync(new FirstPage());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try pushing in this way:

```
await ((MainPage)App.Current.MainPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new mypage());
```

And then call:

```
 Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Comment: Wow that worked, thank you.  I don't understand why, but ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new mypage());
```

and then,

```
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Comment: thanks, that's my go to default navigation. tried that.