# Xamarin Forms Media Plugin - Take photo return to screen pops to root

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm experiencing the issue here on an iOS phone.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/433?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

here's the code that navigates to the photo page.  You can see all the different things I tried

```
   private async void addPhotosClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // await ((RootPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new TakePhoto(_workOrderId));
        //      await ((RootPage)App.Current.MainPage).Detail.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new TakePhoto(_workOrderId));
        //Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        //{
        //     await Navigation.PushAsync(new TakePhoto(_workOrderId));
        //});
        await ((RootPage)App.Current.MainPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new TakePhoto(_workOrderId));
    }
```

On the camera page, there is a camera button icon that invokes the media plugin to take a picture.  When the picture UI returns, it sets an image source to the photo just taken.  The UI returns for a moment, then all of a sudden the app pops back to root

```
   private async Task OnCameraTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        CameraHelper cameraHelper = new CameraHelper();

        try
        {
            ImgBytes = await cameraHelper.TakePicture();

            PhotoImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                return new MemoryStream(ImgBytes);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message == "No camera available")
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "No camera available", "Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Unable to take picture.", "Ok");
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there some sort of work around for this?

Comment: MediaPlugin is an open source project, if you believe you found a bug, it might be a good starting point to contribute to the community.

Comment: Agreed, but for now I'm looking for a work around

Comment: @PatrickGoode Do you put your taking photos code in `cameraHelper.TakePicture()`? This plugin works properly on my side. Which iOS version are you using? Can you share your sample?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  This might be the way I'm using navigation in the app in general.   I saw others had the same issue based on the github link above bit I'm not sure.  Unable to test right now,  but yes camera helper take picture invokes library.   Works on other apps in Android and even inn some iOS. Ill update as soon as i can

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT I can share my sample if you have a way I can get it to you, thanks

Comment: @PatrickGoode You can upload a simple one on the github if possible.

Comment: I have a private repo I can invite you to.  What is your email

Comment: interestingly enough this does not occur on android with the identical code

Comment: I am not sure why you re doing this: ((RootPage)App.Current.MainPage). IOW 
why are you having to cast App.Current.MainPage to RootPage before calling Detail.Navigation? If the Detail page you are on is in a Navigation page then you should just be able to do await Navigation.PushAsync or await Navigation.PushModalAsync. But that looks like something you tried (but for some reason in a Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread)

Comment: I agree, I shouldn't have to do that.   Was basing off here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662823/xamarin-forms-popmodalasync.  I've tried everything until I'm losing my mind.  This works fine on Android. Identical code.  I even tried downloading the source to the media plugin, adding it to the solution and calling that rather than adding it as a nuget so I could step through it.  But I couldn't get it to build

Comment: I tried it with and without being wrapped in main thread.  It turns out its really not the navigation at all.  I can navigate to the page and back out all day long successfully.  Its only when I click the camera button that invokes the media library that pops the whole nav stack.  So weird

Comment: this was solved.  It was the way the master detail page was being set inside on appearing  UGHH!!!

Comment: @PatrickGoode can you explain what you mean by "the way the master detail page was being set inside on appearing..."?

Comment: Best I can do is somehow show you a picture of the diff.  Its kind of complicated.  But I don't know how I would do that here.

Comment: I think the main difference was that it was doing  Detail = NavigationPageHelper.Create(new ContentPage()); and instead I did  Detail = NavigationPageHelper.Create(new Views.MyActualHomePage());.  The first option was put there by Grial Kit template